# Android Studio Emulator Doesn't Open Seperate Window and It Doesn't See Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code

[image]

When I start the emulator in Android Studio, it opens as a tab. I want to open it in a seperate window.
Additionally, my Visual Studio Code doesn't see this emulator.

Also, Android Studio, (and VSCode as well) doesn't see the emulator too. It isn't listed in select device.

I didn't use to have these kind of errors. I needed to delete Android Studio. I reinstalled it and things changed.

Comment: What about [starting the emulator from commandline](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue, go to: `File > settings > tools > emulator`.

After that, untick `"launch in a tool window"` option.

---

## Note:

Restart the program if you couldn't launch the emulator if instead you get a message that it's already launched.

Comment: It's been long since I have uninstalled it. I will try if I need to use it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the new update it's possible to open the emulator as a new window clicking on settings icon -> view mode, there you can choose what's the best for you, maybe it can help.

Comment: I already tried but it doesn't allow that seperate window which consists of nothing but the phone.